# How can I control which results to pass through a UNIX pipe?

Tags: unix, pipe

Is it possible to control which results to pass through the piping operator under UNIX?

For example: suppose I'd like to pipe all output of `foo` to `bar`, **except** for the first result.

Comment: Use another pipe to `tail +2` before.

Comment: @squiguy this works :) If you put it in an answer I'll make sure to accept it.

Comment: Well, I'm not one to repeat answers so @Cairnarvon should get the prize. Glad it worked though!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't see your comment. I didn't mean to snipe your answer.

Comment: @Cairnarvon I'm not about getting all the credit here. As long as people get helped, I'm happy. AKA don't sweat it man :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use other available tools to filter the stream in between your two commands. For your specific example, use [`tail`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail):

```
cmd1 | tail -n +2 | cmd2
```

Other commands you may find valuable are `head`, `grep`, and `sed`.

Comment: I'd probably use `sed 1d` in place of `tail -n +2`, but `tail` works too.